# how can i get a notification when a Process.Start("cmd", "/k ..."); is ready in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows

i'm developing a WPF application which use

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k ...");
```

or

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c ...");
```

to execute some commands throw the command line.
is it possible to get a notification when the command line command is executed and the cmd is "free" again?

its because i need to execute some more command, but i need to execute each command after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need `cmd` here for. If you want to run one command after another, then just execute them one after another directly. You can give `Process.Start` programs to execute and batch files too. If you need a shell built-in such as `dir` then you can use `cmd /c` of course, but `cmd /k` running in the background seems rather unnecessary to me.

In any case, `Process.Start` returns a `Process` object which has a handy method `WaitForExit`. So if you don't start a program that runs indefinitely, as `cmd /k` then you can use that to figure out when the command finished.